# Scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, scope, g++

I accidentally happened to find this in one of the source codes I was looking at. So, I'm giving a similar smaller example here.

In the file *test.h*:

```
#include<iostream>

class test{
    int i;
public:
    test(){}
    //More functions here
};
```

In the file *test.cpp*:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    test test1;
    test::test test2;
    test::test::test test3;
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, is there a reason to declare `test2` that way? Secondly, this code compiles just fine in g++ version 4.4.3 and lower versions. Is there something in the C++ standard, saying, scope resolution operators are ignored when there is no need to resolve scope?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This code is not valid.

It was a bug in g++ that it accepted the code.  See ["g++ does not treat injected class name correctly."](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11764)  The bug was resolved as fixed in 2009, so it should be fixed in any recent version of g++.

Comment: Strange thing: Ideone compiles this code: http://ideone.com/Duwzy
What GCC are they using?

Comment: @kralyk:  Yes.  Observe that ideone is using gcc 4.3.4 and observe that if you compile using its "C++0x" option, which uses gcc 4.5.1, the code is rejected.

Comment: @Ashwin : Your question says it compiles just fine with 4.4.3. ;-]

Comment: Oh I meant versions after 4.4.3 :-)

Answer (score 16):

To clarify the situation, as specified in §9/2:

> A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen. The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name. For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name.

However, as specified in §3.4.3.1/1:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the nested-namespecifier is looked up in the scope of the class (10.2), except for the cases listed below.
>
> [ ... §3.4.3.1/2]:
>
> In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result and the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:
>
> — if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C (Clause 9) [ ... ] the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.
>
> [ ... example: ]

```
struct A { A(); };
[ ... ]
A::A a; // error, A::A is not a type name
struct A::A a2; // object of type A
```