# Why are redundant scope qualifications supported by the compiler, and is it legal?

Tags: c++, scope, definition

I tested on two compilers, and was surprised to see both support the following **definition** without complaint:

```
class A {
  A();
};

A::A::A() {}
   ^^^
```

Note that this also succeeds for methods, although it is flagged when the declaration is over-qualified.

Questions:

- Is this a valid C++ program?
- If so, what purpose does it serve - or is it merely a byproduct?

**Updated Detail:**

In case the original question was not clear or too short: I'm curious why redundant qualifications are permitted on the **definition** (emphasis also added above).

---

*Clang an Apple's GCC 4.2 + LLVM were the compilers*

Comment: This has been asked, but I guess it is a harder dupe to find than some.

Comment: @chris i looked through a few pages, but found nothing -- happy to close if a dup is located. perhaps i just did not search using the proper terms.

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423380/why-are-redundant-class-name-qualifiers-allowed

Comment: @chris Yes. I remember James answering something very similar. But I'm not in the mood to dig through his 2000+ answers.

Comment: @chris i happened to see that before posting, but the over-qualification on the *definition* was what i found odd.

Comment: @Justin, can you find other questions to which the `scope-qualification` tag might apply?  It seems very specific to this question and this question only...

Comment: @Charles just search "qualification c++", and you will find some out of the 399 results. can you think of a preferable synonym that might apply?

Comment: @Mysticial:  [Scope resolution operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050863/scope-resolution-operator)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed (§9/2):

> The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name. For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name.

For information about the reasoning that lead to class name inject, you might want to read [N0444](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1994/N0444.pdf).

Comment: thanks (+1) -- i have revised the question to emphasize that the *definition* was the part that was really curious to me (and i realize that may not change your answer).