# Is it OK to specify a duplicate C++ class scope?

Tags: c++, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are redundant scope qualifications supported by the compiler, and is it legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135498/why-are-redundant-scope-qualifications-supported-by-the-compiler-and-is-it-lega)

I wouldn't expect this to compile but it does. Could this be a compiler bug, or does it have some correct meaning?

```
$ g++ -c scopes.cpp
$ cat scopes.cpp
class Log {
public:
    Log() { }
    static void fn() { }
};

void test() {
    Log::Log::Log::Log::Log::Log::fn();
}

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
```

Comment: Side note:  This will not compile under VC10.  However, just as a compiler accepting code doesn't prove it's legal, also just because a compiler rejects code doesn't mean it's illegal.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's legal.  A class's name is inserted into its own namespace, which is called the *injected-class-name*.  From C++03 §9/2:

> [...] The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.
>   For purposes of access checking, the *injected-class-name* is treated as if it were a public member name.

Note that `Log::Log` names the class constructor, which is only allowed in certain contexts, but as long as you end the chain of `Log::Log::...` with something other than `Log` (such as `fn`), then it doesn't name the constructor.  Specifically, §3.4.3.1/1a says:

> If the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`, and the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*,
>   when looked up in `C`, is the injected-class-name of `C` (clause 9), the name is instead considered to name the
>   constructor of class `C`. Such a constructor name shall be used only in the *declarator-id* of a constructor definition
>   that appears outside of the class definition.

Comment: It is absolutely legal. Try compiling it.

Comment: @John: Why do you still doubt that it's legal after seeing citations from the C++ language standard and after multiple compilers accept it without warnings/errors?

Comment: It is legal because it's defined behaviour, documented in the spec.

Comment: @John: Well your common sense is wrong.  This may not by what you might expect, but it's how the language works, for better or for worse.

Comment: OK, after reading the link provided by @Luchian Grigore (in the OP) and the various sections in the Spec, I withdraw my doubts that this is legal.