# C++ class function return type definition, return a class

Tags: c++, syntax, g++

I have a vector class look like this:

```
class Vector3
{

 public:
   Vector3(){m_x = m_y = m_z = 0.0f;}
   Vector3(const float & i_x, const float & i_y, const float & i_z):
     m_x(i_x), 
     m_y(i_y),
     m_z(i_z)
     {}

   Vector3 operator+(const Vector3 & i_other);
private:
   float m_x;
   float m_y;
   float m_z;
};

Vector3::Vector3 Vector3::operator+(const Vector3 & i_other)
{
   float tx = m_x + i_other.m_x;
   float ty = m_y + i_other.m_y;
   float tz = m_z + i_other.m_z;
   return Vector3(tx, ty, tz);
}
```

Obviously, the `Vector3::operator+` definition synax is wrong because the return type is `Vector3::Vector3`, not `Vector3`. `Vector3::Vector3` means there is a namespace `Vector3`, and inside the name space there is a class `Vector3`. But I only have a class `Vector3`, no namespace here.

My question is, in Ubuntu 12.04, the syntax above can not be compiled (Ubuntu's g++ compiler is [gcc version 4.6.3]). However, in Mac, g++ can compile the code(Mac's g++ compiler is [gcc version 4.2.1]). Also, I test this syntax in a Red Hat linux machine, it also works (g++ version is [gcc version 4.4.6])

So, is it different version of gcc have different compile principle? Or, my g++ in Ubuntu broke?

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135498/why-are-redundant-scope-qualifications-supported-by-the-compiler-and-is-it-lega

Comment: Not an answer, but: What is the point of passing the floating point arguments as references to the constructor?

Comment: @jogojapan: Maybe for floating point, it is not necessary to pass a reference. But I think using constance reference to pass parameter can make the code solid.

Comment: @chris Thank you. So in this case, the compiler in Ubuntu doesn't support name injection?

Comment: @geekmayplay If you worry about accidently modifying the argument inside the constructor, you can use `const float` (instead of `const float &`).

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, you are right. But my point is no matter how large a float is, I just passing a reference to it, so that the passing space cost is the same, is the size of a reference. I mean maybe for different platform, floating point maybe 32 bits or 64bits, or whatever.

Comment: @geekmayplay If you are lucky, the compiler will optimize the reference away and use the float directly. If not, it's safe to assume that the reference will take at least as much space as the float, and adds a level of indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older compiler is incorrect. Little surprise there.

It is probably parsing `Vector3::Vector3` as an injected-type-name. Inside the scope of `class Vector3 { }`, the identifier `Vector3` refers to the class, not the constructor (except when you're declaring the constructor, of course). And at first glance, you might think it means the same thing in a return type, because §3.4/3 (I'm using the C++11 standard here) says

> The injected-class-name of a class (Clause 9) is also considered to be a member of that class for the purposes of name hiding and lookup.

Digging deeper, in §3.4.3.1/2,

> In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result and the nested-name-specifier nominates
>   a class C:
>
> — if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name
>   of C (Clause 9)
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.

The context of starting a declaration with an injected-class-name happens to be the same as in defining a constructor outside `class {}` scope, a la

```
class Vector3 { … };

Vector3::Vector3(){m_x = m_y = m_z = 0.0f;}
```

The older GCC noticed that the declaration wasn't a constructor, then took a fallback path that did work. However that fallback was illegal because C++ specifies that in a context where the constructor could be the result of the lookup, it is the only valid lookup result.

In all probability, some user took the time to file a bug, and a GCC developer took the time to diagnose this, fix it, and write a testcase. Multiply across the number of trivialities in a complex language like C++, and you start to appreciate the effort put into your compiler.