# Meaning of a structname inside namespace of struct?

Tags: c++, clang

What does it mean if I write:

```
struct Str1 {
   char val1;
};

struct Str2 {
   struct Str1::Str1 valS;
};
```

what does the added qualification `::Str1` mean?

Bonus points: How to match this one with a clang ASTMatcher ;-)

Greetings

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135498/why-are-redundant-scope-qualifications-supported-by-the-compiler-and-is-it-lega

Comment: I'd like to see an example of when `struct Str1::Str1` provides benefit over just `Str1`, or disambiguates something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
Str1 valS;
```

the extra `struct Str1::` is redundant.  See [N0444](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1994/N0444.pdf)