# writing class name twice in outside member function definition

Tags: c++, g++

why writing `class name` twice in outside member function definition works?

Example:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class test
{
    public:
    void get();
};
void test::test::get()
{
    cout<<"Get() called";
}
int main( )
{ 
    test a;
    a.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why `test::test::get()` works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135498/why-are-redundant-scope-qualifications-supported-by-the-compiler-and-is-it-lega, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050863/scope-resolution-operator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423380/why-are-redundant-class-name-qualifiers-allowed

Comment: @chris I got my answer , So how could I close this question?